# How can I customize the default html file returned on custom http error codes

Tags: java, google-app-engine

In my app I would like to return error codes and set the error message on the server. This is what I use:

```
response.setStatus(530);
response.sendError(530, e.getMessage());
```

When I return a custom error like that, app engine always sends the error codes and status wrapped in a default html template. In javascript:

```
$(document).ajaxError(function (event, request, settings) {
        // request.statusText is always "Internal Server Error" 
        // and not my custom status message
        // request.responseText is an html string
    });
```

by the way, in the development server it's different. statusText **is** my custom error text

Answer (score 1):

In your web.xml file, you can specify the jsp to serve on specific error codes:

```
<error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/WEB-INF/jsp/errors/404.jsp</location>
</error-page>
<error-page>
    <error-code>500</error-code>
    <location>/WEB-INF/jsp/errors/500.jsp</location>
</error-page>
```

The jsp will be rendered as needed.

Note that this doesn't work correctly in the local devserver, you'll need to deploy to see it in action. To help with development, you can load the error page directly as a jsp.

Error page rendering only happens when you `resp.sendError(code)` - if you just do `resp.setStatus(code, message)` the servlet container will not handle errors like this. This enables you to still, for example, return json and an error code for ajax calls.

If you haven't specified a page, the servlet container serves HTML at it's discretion (as you've already seen).